# python http lib automatically determine the type of authentication

Tags: python-requests, urllib2, httplib

I have a problem that I known the web services require authentication,but I can't determine Basic or Digest it need,How can I deal with this situation use python2.7 http library that I have own the username and password？

Answer (score 0):

You should use requests.It has requests_toolbelt lib for auto check authentication type,the following sample code:

```
import requests
import requests_toolbelt

auth = requests_toolbelt(username,password)
req = requests.get(url,auth=auth)
```